# concatenating an action with a string using dynamics

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have the following code in C#:

```
Action a = new Action(() => Console.WriteLine());
dynamic d = a;
d += "???";
Console.WriteLine(d);
```

and the output is

System.Action???

while if you add an int instead of a string to d it would throw an exception.

Can you please explain why does this happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this happens because when you use `d += "???";` d is converted to string (using default `ToString()` method which takes object name) and then "???" is appended and wrote to console.
If you try to use `d += 2` this fails because there's no default way to convert an Action to an integer. Same for other types...

Comment: if i use some other type for 'a' it would give an exception

Comment: @OrlandoWilliam: yes, sure. The reason is (I tried to explain in my answer, maybe I was not clear, sorry) that there is no default _"converter"_ between Action and other types but string...

Comment: @OrlandoWilliam: No it wouldn't. Any object can be converted to a string in this way. Try: `object a = 2;
a += "???";
Console.WriteLine(a);`, for example.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior edited.. it's not another type for 'a' it's the string i add who i change... and it's not to just some other type it's to int, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

Adding a `string` to anything in .NET will cause that thing's `.ToString` method to be called, and treat the addition as a string concatenation. The same thing would happen if you weren't using a `dynamic`.

```
Action a = new Action(() => Console.WriteLine());
Console.WriteLine(a + "???"); // outputs "System.Action???"
```

Any `Action` will return `System.Action` when its `.ToString` method is called.

The only difference between `+=` in the original example and the `+` in this example is that you are setting the result of the concatenation into the dynamic variable. It would be equivalent to:

```
object a = new Action(() => Console.WriteLine());
a = a + "???"; // The same as: a = a.ToString() + "???";
Console.WriteLine(a);
```

Comment: the compiler wouldn't allow it if i weren't using dynamic

Comment: @OrlandoWilliam: Sure it would, if you cast `d` as an object instead. See my update.

Comment: you are right, I changed something else checking other things that's why it threw exception